# EAI_NODATA and EAI_ADDRFAMILY undeclared (Linux OS)

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, compilation

Does anybody know why those constants fail to compile? I changed gcc and it looks that I have problems with some dev libraries.

I was thinking to fix it with -DDEAI_ADDRFAMILY -DEAI_NODATA in the CCFLAGS.

Does it ring a bell?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are missing an include file

```
#include <netdb.h>
```

Comment: Defining `_GNU_SOURCE` is also necessary.